# C# Time conversion to GMT(UK summer Time) with considering Day Light Saving ,Offset on UK & on Hosting Location (US)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, timezone, gmt, datetime-conversion

Basically I want to convert US time (hosting Server time) to GMT (UK Summer Time)

technology C#, .NET 4.0, TimeZoneInfoClass

Detailed scenario:

I am creating a SMS sending application.It should not send sms from 10.00PM to 6.30 AM UK Time or GMT.

Server resides in US or suppose anywhere in the world.

So my approach is

- I am assuming that Hosting server has Auto Day Light Adjusting Patch. So I don't check for hosting Server daylight saving. Is that Ok??
- It adjust for US time automatically & I will get correct time through `UTCNow()`
- I get GMT time from `timezoneinfoclass` or `Time.UTCNow()` method. Now I have correct UTC time & I have to check for Daylight saving a/c to UK time (targeted timezone)
- lastly I check parameter for targeted timezone (i.e UK) like `Datetime,UTCoffset,IsDayLightSaving,SupportDaylightSaving` based on  Machine Time Zone ID  (GMT time zone London..).  eg:-timezoneid.local.searchbyma..(GMT)  //*Syntax)

  ```
  if (IsDayLightSaving==true)
  {
      UTC.AddHours(1)   //syntax is not correct
  }
  else
  {
      // GMT= UK time
  }
  ```

OS I Have following questions :-

1. Is This a good approach or flawed one ? What are the alternatives?
2. Should I check for daylight saving for hosting timezone & then correct the offset by adding one hour if it is DST ??
3. Any free reliable web services for getting GMT time?

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the DateTimeOffset class?

Comment: Ok  I have  solved it with  DateTimeOffset class

Comment: Please can you say how you solved it?

Comment: TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time");
TimeSpan offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);

DateTime testDateTime = DateTime.Now.Add(offset);